# Validating JWT stored as an HTTP cookie in a MERN application on the frontend

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern

I'm developing a MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) application where I save a JWT as an HTTP cookie after a user logs in. This JWT has a 2-hour expiration time. My current focus is on establishing a frontend mechanism to verify the legitimacy of this JWT cookie. How can I go about achieving this? Additionally, when the cookie is found to be invalid, I intend to log out the user.

On the backend, I've already implemented measures to remove the cookie and expire the token. I'm specifically seeking the best practices for handling this validation process on the frontend.

Thank you for your assistance

I've made an API request in the App component, and with each rerender, it sends a request to verify the validity of the token. However, I don't believe this is a good practice.

Comment: You make a request with the cookie, if the request fails with a 401 you either refresh or you logout the user by forcing them to authenticate. Dont do security things in the client. The cookie should have httpOnly set and not be accessible by the client javascript.

Comment: Why does the legitimacy need to be specifically verified. Normally the only verification needed is any request to the backend that needs authentication. So whenever the backend responds with a 401 unauthorised you redirect to the logout page and throw the invalid token away